# How anchor tag is firing an HTML Action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:-

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><b>Contact</b> <span style="color: #f00; font-size: larger;">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls input-append">
        <input disabled="disabled" style="width: 210px" type="text" id="id-lookup-addjllcontact-contactid" defaultoid=""
               defaultvalue="" oid="" value=""
               field="SystemUserId" otype="systemuser">
        <a class="btn"  id="btn-lookup-addjllcontact-contactid"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
            @Html.Action("_LookupSearchPartial", "Lookup",
                    new
                    {
                        ParentFormId = "form-addjllcontact",
                        LookupInputId = "id-lookup-addjllcontact-contactid",
                        LookupButtonId = "btn-lookup-addjllcontact-contactid",
                        UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        EntityType = "systemuser",
                        AttributeName = "systemuserid",
                        AttributeDisplayName = "FullName"
                    })
    </div>
```

When I click anchor with id as "btn-lookup-addjllcontact-contactid", it fires the HTML Action. Can any one tell me how ? Also I want to know how can display the result of the HTML Action in a modal.

Comment: You `<a>` tag does not fire the `@Html.Action(..)` code - `@Html.Action()` is server side code and its html is rendered in the view when the page is first loaded. Its not clear what you are claiming. I assume you must have some javascript handling the `.click()` event of the link.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I tried looking for that .click event but could not find it. That's why I asked. I click on the anchor and it reloads the result of HTML Action ??

Comment: Is this something what you want: `$('#btn-lookup-addjllcontact-contactid').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); // show Html.Action contents })`? Still unclear if the `Html.Action` is already rendered on view and you just want to toggle its visibility, or using AJAX to load the partial view.

Comment: Then you must have a script somewhere making an ajax call to your `_LookupSearchPartial()` method (or are you really refreshing the whole page?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was Javascript in the page somewhere hidden which was doing it. This was a generic javascript file that was handling all the lookups in the application.

```
this.lookupInput = $('#' + this._config.LookupInputId);

this.lookupButton.live("click", this, JLL.Lookup.Search.showLookup);
```